# Is it possible to charge a panasonic HDC SD900 while filming?

Tags: camera

On this camera, the battery can only be charged inside the camera. So I cannot charge one battery while using an other.
My only alternative is to charge while I film. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

I first asked the question on a [youtube video reviewing the camera](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8A5GEk83NJk). And I got the folowing response:

> Yes, it works. You can do anything while charging.

Now, I have bought the camera and tried it myself, and I confirm that **Yes, is it possible to charge a panasonic HDC SD900 while filming**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know on this exact model, but if it has a dedicated power port, then it should be able to charge while filming.